# Pass PHP variable within echo <script> content

Tags: javascript, php, query-string, key-value

I am trying to pass $php_variable to JavaScript content **in echo tag in one php file**. It is because I hope to append the query value from old_page_url to new_page_url by using `window.location`.

For example,

`http://example/?data=1234` to `http://example/something-else/1234`

My code snippet:

```
<?php

$php_variable = "testing";
echo "<script>";
echo "var toURL = 'http://example.com/something-else/'";
echo "window.location = toURL + $php_variable";
echo "</script>";
```

I have tried:

```
<?php

$php_variable = "testing";
echo "<script>";
echo "var toURL = 'http://example.com/something-else/'";
echo "window.location = toURL + json_decode($php_variable)";
echo "</script>";
```

and

```
<?php

$php_variable = "testing";
echo "<script>";
echo "var toURL = 'http://example.com/something-else/'";
echo "window.location = toURL + <?php echo $php_variable; ?>";
echo "</script>";
```

But these two don't work. Any idea?

#### Update: Final Code Snippet

```
<?php

$php_variable = "testing";
$toURL = "http://example.com/something-else";
echo "<script>";
echo "window.location = '$toURL/$php_variable'";
echo "</script>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "window.location = 'http://example.com/something-else/$php_variable'";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
<?php
$php_variable = "testing";
echo "<script>";
echo "var toURL = 'http://example.com/something-else/'";
echo "window.location = toURL +" . "'{$php_variable}'";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: Add the js output to your question with this sol

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: The output that's coming in the webpage

Comment: I have edited the answer, is that what you want exactly?

Comment: The page is not redirected. The php_variable is not appending too. I tried to alert it out to see whether it is appending. Nope.